# How to get RequestHeader default value in interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, header, interceptor

I have an interceptor:

```
public class SomeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Header: " + request.getHeader("defaultHeader"));

        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity someMethod(@RequestHeader(name = "defaultHeader", defaultValue = "someValue", required = false) final String someValue) {
        //do something
}
```

Is there any way to get default value of "someValue" inside interceptor? Or is there any way to make an annotation which will take this default value before executing any operation inside "someMethod"? Or any other way to take this "someValue" without writing anything inside "someMethod"?

Comment: In theory you get the `handler` and can use reflection to pull that out. The simple answer is no as the controller is called after the interceptors have finished processing.

Answer (score 0):

In the interceptor pre-handle method, use boilerplate code to check for the header. If not present, set the default value. And in the controller assume that the header is always present.